# How do I get this to work--2 critical errors that I don't understand?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () // print to console: 3.0*5.0=15.00
{
    double a;
    double b;
    a =(3.0);
    b =(5.0);
    cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "* " << b << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "------" << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision (2) << a*b << "\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int calculate () // print to console: (7.1*8.3)-2.2=56.73
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    a = (7.1);
    b = (8.3);
    c = (2.2);
    cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "* " << b << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "- " << c << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "------" << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << (a*b)-c << "\n" << endl;
    return (a*b)-c;
}

int calculation () // print to console: 3.2/(6.1*5.0)=0.10
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    a=(3.2);
    b=(6.1);
    c=(5.0);
    cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
    cout << b << "*" << c << endl; 
    cout << "------" << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << a/(b*c) << "\n" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return a/(b*c);
}
```

I've never encountered this error. I am new to c++ so some direction would be great! How can I change this code in order to get it to print without flashing. Thank you!

Output:
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: What is the subsystem seting value?

Comment: Project -> Properties -> Linker -> System -> Subsystem. What is the value?

Comment: Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)....what should it be? I don't see a number?

Comment: If I remember correctly, last time I got this error, it was set to Windows. Console is the correct setting in this case.

Comment: Please do not pick up the habit of putting [system("PAUSE");](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) in your code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Please explain why system("PAUSE") is evil. Is it because it is not portable?

Comment: How many of you are working on this [exact same code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541169/what-is-missing-in-this-c-program-printing-calculations)?

Comment: What happened to your formatting?

Comment: @Hindol: It's because as a C++ programmer, you have no way to know what the `PAUSE` command on a platform does. There are much more effective way to wait for a keypress. And getting into the habit of doing it breaks things like pipelines and non-interactive programs. Also, it serves no purpose -- you can just as well terminate as wait to terminate. If someone invoked a console program without a console, it would only be because they didn't want it to hang around.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - unfortunately, some IDE's don't understand that a command-line program needs to hang around long enough for the user to see what they did.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Command line programs are designed to be run from a command line. I wouldn't break my programs to make them work better with broken IDEs. (And even if I had to, my objection is to making a habit out of it. If you understand it's a horrible workaround to broken IDEs, then with luck you won't make a habit out of doing it.)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your [.cpp] file is not part of the project's source files, and thus it's not compiled, and no corresponding object code file is linked.

Reproducing the error:

```
[d:\dev\test]
> type nul >bah.rc

[d:\dev\test]
> rc /nologo bah.rc

[d:\dev\test]
> dir /b *.res
bah.res

[d:\dev\test]
> link /nologo bah.res /out:bah.exe /entry:mainCRTStartup /subsystem:console /machine:x86
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
bah.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```

Solution: add the file to the Visual Studio project (and not as a solution file).

---

Regarding the code, try this:

```
#include <iostream>         // std::wcout, std::endl, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>          // std::setprecision
#include <string>           // std::wstring
using namespace std;

void display( char const expression[], double const result )
{
    wcout << expression << " = " << result << endl;
}

#define DISPLAY( expr ) display( #expr, expr )

int main()
{
    wcout << fixed << setprecision( 1 );
    DISPLAY( 3.0*5.0 );
    DISPLAY( (7.1*8.3)-2.2 );
    DISPLAY( 3.2/(6.1*5.0) );
}
```

I wouldn't ordinarily just present a solution for a typical homework problem.

But your attempted solution seems to be headed in a wrong (not good for learning) direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check/Update this variable:

[image]

This setting controls the name of your "main" function. In other words, this setting tells linker what name it should look for when it starts the linking process. There are about 8 subsystemss and each has its own "main".

Comment: The error message is a bit more subtle than a missing `main`. It's a missing entrypoint in the runtime library. See my answer for one (and probably the only) way that that can occur.